# devtoolset-4 was removed from centos-release-scl?

Tags: centos, gcc

I need to install gcc 4.9 on CentOS 6. And I usually do the following:

```
yum install -y centos-release-scl
yum install -y devtoolset-3-gcc-c++ make cmake re2c libuuid-devel libxml2-devel zlib-devel
```

Today I found out that only devtoolset-6 and devtoolset-7 are available now, all other version are removed.

Any ideas? I can't use gcc >= 5.

**EDIT**

As yumNoob suggested, devtoolset [can be found here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/)

So I created a repo file,

```
[sclo]
name=devtoolset-34
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

And it fails with

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

So the baseurl in incorrect, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Forgot to mention how to install SCL in the first place

Install the repo configs

```
$ yum install centos-release-scl
```

(installs centos-release-scl and centos-release-scl-rh)

Give

`yum-config-manager --enable centos-sclo-rh-testing`

a try. Not obvious as to me http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/ still contains all versions from devtoolset 3 up to 7.

EDIT 2:
Turns out even enabling centos-sclo-rh-testing doesn't really solve the problem as yum tries to install devtoolset-3-binutils for el7 which requires glibc-2.14...
Manual downloading of the required RPMs from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-3/ seems the only option at the moment

Comment: Does not work on centos 6, can you provide a `.repo` file? See my update

Comment: devtoolset-4 does install without the problem noticed with devtoolset-3.